# JavaFX How can i save file with tabs?

Tags: select, tabs, save, javafx-8

I have a tabbed editor with TextArea and I want to save the selected file's textarea content.

But how can I do this?

Here I have my items defined (or what it's called on english. I'm danish) :

```
public static TabPane pane = new TabPane();
public static TextArea area;
public static ListView lines;
public static VBox box;
public static Tab tabs;
public static BorderPane bps;
```

My code for adding a tab:

```
public static void AddTab(String title, String con) {
    area = new TextArea();
    lines = new ListView();

    box = new VBox();
    bps = new BorderPane();
    bps.setLeft(lines);
    bps.setRight(area);
    box.getChildren().addAll(bps);

    tabs = new Tab(title);
    tabs.setContent(box);
    pane.getTabs().add(tabs);
}
```

When i add a tab i use this code :

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < GUI.Editor.pane.getTabs().size(); i++) {

}

String title = "New File (" + i + ")";
GUI.Editor.AddTab(title, null);

GUI.Editor.pane.getSelectionModel().select(i);
```

But how can I save a file on this way?.

Oh and of course I know I need a file dialog (and I have try to save file).

The only thing I will need is how to get the content from the selected tab (when I mean content I mean the TextArea's content).

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting tab content is VBox it's bit difficult to get the TextArea directly. One way is by doing multiple type casts from VBox to Textarea we can get the selected area.

```java
private static TextArea getSelectedTabContent() {
        Node selectedTabContent = pane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent();
        if(selectedTabContent instanceof VBox){
            Node borderPane =  ((VBox) selectedTabContent).getChildren().get(0);
            if(borderPane instanceof BorderPane){
                Node textAreaNode = ((BorderPane) borderPane).getRight();
                if(textAreaNode instanceof  TextArea){
                    return (TextArea) textAreaNode;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below is the complete code to save to file.

```java
package com.pw.jnotepad.app;

import com.pw.jnotepad.app.providers.AlertBox;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class StackOverflowAnswer extends Application {
    public static TabPane pane = new TabPane();
    public static TextArea area;
    public static ListView lines;
    public static VBox box;
    public static Tab tabs;
    public static BorderPane bps;
    public static Stage window;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        area = new TextArea();
        lines = new ListView();

        box = new VBox();
        bps = new BorderPane();
        bps.setTop(createMenuBar());
        bps.setLeft(lines);
        bps.setRight(area);
        box.getChildren().addAll(bps);

        tabs = new Tab("tab-1");
        tabs.setContent(box);
        pane.getTabs().add(tabs);


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    // to create menu bar with file menu
    private static MenuBar createMenuBar(){
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem("Save");
        saveFile.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Save file action triggered");
            FileChooser fileChooser = createFileChooser("Save File");
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
            if(selectedFile != null){
                File savedFile =  saveTextToFile(selectedFile);
                if(savedFile!= null){
                    System.out.println("file saved successfully");
                    updateTabTitle(savedFile.getName());
                }
            }


        });
        fileMenu.getItems().addAll(saveFile);
        return new MenuBar(fileMenu);
    }

    // to open save dialog window
    private static FileChooser createFileChooser(String title) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter onlyTextFilesFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Txt files(*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(onlyTextFilesFilter);
        fileChooser.setTitle(title);
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toFile());
        return fileChooser;
    }
   // to save the file into disk
    public static File saveTextToFile(File file) {
            TextArea selectedTabContent = getSelectedTabContent();
            if(selectedTabContent!=null){
                try(BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));) {
                    ObservableList<CharSequence> paragraphs =  selectedTabContent.getParagraphs();
                    paragraphs.forEach(charSequence -> {
                        try {
                            buffer.append(charSequence);
                            buffer.newLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("failed to write to text file.");
                            AlertBox.display("File Save Error", "failed to write to text file.");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                    buffer.flush();
                    return file;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("failed to write to text file.");
                    AlertBox.display("File Save Error", "failed to write to text file.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    // to get selected text area
    private static TextArea getSelectedTabContent() {
        Node selectedTabContent = pane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent();
        if(selectedTabContent instanceof VBox){
            Node borderPane =  ((VBox) selectedTabContent).getChildren().get(0);
            if(borderPane instanceof BorderPane){
                Node textAreaNode = ((BorderPane) borderPane).getRight();
                if(textAreaNode instanceof  TextArea){
                    return (TextArea) textAreaNode;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    // to update tab title by saved file name
    private static void updateTabTitle(String name){
        pane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setText(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know it's very old question but thought of it may be useful for someone who is facing same issue.